# Active class conflict in two div

Tags: jquery, html

I have two different sections with the ".is-active" class. The first one is used to toggle between the dropdown links and the second one is to toggle between the tab links. However, the first one i.e., the dropdown links ".is-active" class isn't removing when it isn't active.

Here is the code for the two:

```
  var selector = ".dropdown-container .dropdown-item";
  $(selector).on("click", function() {
  $(selector).removeClass("is-active");
  $(this).addClass("is-active");
  });

  //Tabs .is-active
  var selector = ".tabs li";
  $(selector).on("click", function() {
  $(selector).removeClass("is-active");
  $(this).addClass("is-active");
  });
```

I moved the dropdown jquery code below the tabs jquery code and now the problem is reversed. Now, the tabs ".is-active" class isn't removing when it isn't active.

Here is the HTML markup:

```
//Dropdown container
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12-12 col-md-12-12">
      <a href="#" class="btn is-success is-outlined is-medium"
        >Hello World<i class="fab fa-adobe icon is-small"></i
      ></a>
      <div class="dropdown is-right-aligned">
        <button class="btn is-primary is-outlined is-medium toggle">
          Dropdown Menu
          <i class="fas fa-angle-down icon is-small"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#!" class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
            <a href="#!" class="dropdown-item">Another action</a>
            <a href="#!" class="dropdown-item">Something</a>
            <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
            <a href="#!" class="dropdown-item">Report</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

//Tabs container
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12-12 col-md-12-12">
        <div class="tabs is-full-width mt-from-md-5 mb-from-xs-4">
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active">
              <a href="#tab1" class="tab-item">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#!" class="tab-item">Features</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!" class="tab-item"
                ><i class="fab fa-adobe icon is-small"></i>Fox-Flex</a
              >
            </li>
            <li><a href="#!" class="tab-item">Pictures</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!" class="tab-item"
                ><i class="fab fa-adobe icon is-small"></i>Documents</a
              >
            </li>
            <li><a href="#!" class="tab-item">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!" class="tab-item">Videos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I know that the code is conflicting in some way, but could not figure out how to solve. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is caused by using using the same variable (`selector` twice), this causes the first one to overwritten and point to the wrong element in click handlers. This problem can be fixed to using different variable names:

```
var dropdownSelector = ".dropdown-container .dropdown-item";
 $(dropdownSelector).on("click", function() {
   $(dropdownSelector).removeClass("is-active");
   $(this).addClass("is-active");
});

//Tabs .is-active
var selector = ".tabs li";
$(selector).on("click", function() {
    $(selector).removeClass("is-active");
    $(this).addClass("is-active");
});
```

Comment: Could you mark it as solution to help other people? @AbeidAhmed

Comment: Yes, sir. Sorry for the delay.